# Given speed and turn radius, can police catch suspect?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, plane-geometry

Cars are points in an infinite plane.
There are no roads or obstacle, the cars can travel the plane with no restrictions.

Each car has a speed, turn radius, initial position and initial direction (heading).

There are two cars. One is called police, the other is the suspect. Police wants to chase the other (be in the same position at the same time), suspects wants to evade police.

How to find out if this is possible?

There is infinite visibility and zero reaction time.

Example 1: if suspect's speed is higher than police then he will evade if he travels in a straight line away from police.
Example 2: if police's speed is higher than the suspect's car and if the turn radius is the same or smaller, then police can just follow the suspect's trajectory to catch him.

The question is what happens in the middle cases. If the police is faster but has a bigger turn radius (less maneuverability), in what cases will he be able to catch the suspect.

Comment: The police will never be able to catch the suspect if they are both simply points.

Comment: @Lovsovs Damn engineers amirite? OP, before the pedantic mathematicians of SE assault you, define catch to be within an $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of the suspect.

Comment: Also to clarify, can you elaborate on how exactly you want to define turn radius?